# Mobile website works on .com domain but not .se?

Tags: html, css, mobile, viewport

I have two domains that point to the same directory. If a mobile is detected it will show a mobile version of the site via PHP. This changes some of the HTML and the stylesheet.

If I go to

> maredovisning.com

The mobile version works without issues. However if I go to

> maredovisning.se

The mobile version is broken, it seems like the viewport is not working correctly but I am unsure as to what the actual issue is?

Comment: Without seeing any code, I'd bet my money on the .htaccess-file or the php doing the detection. Maybe some error because .se is only the characters but .com is four?

Comment: There is no .htaccess file and the php uses a variable $ismobile which is true on both domains. So the mobile version of the site is displayed on both domains but it does not look the same.

Comment: Seems to be an issue with the webhost using frames or something instead of an actual DNS redirect